# Installing PokerStars software problem

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, wine

Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon, Wine HQ installed. Installing the PokerStars Poker app with Wine The installation works fine but crashes when I try to log in. How to get it working?

Answer (score 3):

The [wine appdb entry on pokerstars](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2899&sAllBugs) has links to several bug reports about PokerStars crashing on Wine. I think you can't get it to run successfully until those have been fixed.